# How do I append values to the props of a react components children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am wondering whether the following I want to do it possible. Essentially, I am planning on creating a bunch of tsx components which allow me to create CSS Grids in component form. Here is what I imagined:

```
<Grid limit={12}>
    <Cell width={6} />
    <Cell width={6} />
</Grid>
```

In this case, the grid should limit the width to 12, and the Cells should work on that value. So in this example:

```
grid-column: 6 / 12;
```

So, for convenience purposes, it would be awesome if I could do something like this within the Grid.tsx component:

```
export const Grid: React.FC<GridProps> = ({ 
    className,
    style,
    children,
}) => {

    const classes = classNames({
        "grid": true,
    });

    children?.forEach(x => x.props["limit"] = 12);

    return (
        <div 
            className={`${classes} ${className}`}
            style={style}>
            { children }
        </div>
    )
}
```

so that I don't have to specify the limit for every child Cell explicitly.

However, I have yet to figure out how. Is there a way to do this, extending the props of a child components from the respective parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). This will preserve existing props on the child elements.

```
import React, { cloneElement } from 'react';

export const Grid = ({ children, limit }) => (
   <div>
      {
         children.map(child => (
            cloneElement(child, { limit })
         )
      }
   </div>
);
```